# how to stop creation opportunities and lead on chatter?

Tags: opportunity, chatter-feed

i enabled chatter feed tracking for a custom object and included this chatter for the records in visualforce using chatter:feedwithFollowers component.

when i open a record in this object, i am also seeing an option to create opportunities and leads through this chatter feed just like posting something on chatter.

does somebody know how to disable or remove this option from custom object chatter feed tracking?

Comment: you can remove those two button from "Feed Item Layouts" , i think those button were present in the layout.

Comment: As far as I know, these Feed Item layouts are configured at org level but not every object. I want to make these changes only for a specific object. is there any alternate way to achieve this?